# Having trouble with Arrays :/

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

So far here is my code

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0)); 
    int inputnum,occurrences;
    occurrences = 0;
    cout<<"Enter a number to check the occurences"<<endl;
    cin>>inputnum;
    int arrayofnum[10] = {(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201),(rand()%201)} ;
    cout<<arrayofnum[0]<<","<<arrayofnum[1]<<","<<arrayofnum[2]<<","<<arrayofnum[3]<<","<<arrayofnum[4]<<","<<arrayofnum[5]<<","<<arrayofnum[6]<<","<<arrayofnum[7]<<","<<arrayofnum[8]<<","<<arrayofnum[9]<<endl;
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(inputnum == arrayofnum[i])
            occurrences++;
    }

    cout<<"The number of occurrences of "<<inputnum<<"in the random list is "<<occurrences<<" times"<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is  to check how many times the number inputted is shown in the array
However the if statement seems to be giving me trouble can anyone help?

Comment: Aside from you're using wrong array indexing (array starts with 0, not with 1; and last element would be 9), what exactly is your problem? What have you entered? What output have you got? What output do you expect?

Comment: You might want to explain in more detail what "trouble" means.  A specific error message here might help you avoid getting downvoted too much more.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see how your code is executed and what the values of the variables are at every line in your code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're accessing past the end of the array:

```
if (inputnum == arrayofnum[i])
```

Your for-loop allows `i` to take the value of 10 before terminating, so in the final iteration you would be accessing `arrayofnum[10]`.  The last element in the array is `arrayofnum[9]`.

Remember that arrays in c++ are zero-based, so you just need to adjust your for-loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   /* stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
```

to this,

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

to see if there is anything happens

Answer (score 0):

replace `for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)` by

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

your array starts at index 0

Answer (score 0):

From the way you have `cout'ed` the `arrayofnum`, I am assuming that you do know the working of arrays and its boundaries, i.e., the arrays start from `index 0` and ends at `maxCount-1`. So, now you have to take a look on your `for` loop and you are good to go.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

your for loop is incorrect
it should be 
`for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`
as the size of array is 10 so you should iterate from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done very easily. Here's how I would do it:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main() {
    int i , user_input , lim , mod , cn ;
    lim = 10 ;
    mod = 201 ;
    cn = 0 ;
    int arr[ lim ] ;
    for( i = 0 ; i < lim ; i++ ) {
        arr[ i ] = rand() % mod ;
    }
    cout << "Enter a number to check the occurences\n" ;
    cin >> user_input ;
    for( i = 0 ; i < lim ; i++ ) {
        if( i != 0 ) {
            cout << "," ;
        }
        cout << arr[ i ] ;
        if( arr[ i ] == user_input ) {
            cn++ ;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n" ;
    cout << "The number of occurrences of " << user_input << " in the random list is "     << cn << " times" << "\n" ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Also you are accessing a position in the array which does not exists. Valid indices of your array are [0,10].